Satake isomorphism between $\mathcal{H}(\mathrm{SL}_n)$ and $R[\mathrm{PGL}_n]$
I'm looking for a reference that explains/computes the explicit Satake isomorphism between $\mathcal{H}(\mathrm{SL}_{n})$ and the representation ring of the dual group $R(\mathrm{PGL}_{n})$, where the Hecke algebra is over a $p$-adic field. The case of $\mathcal{H}(\mathrm{PGL}_{2}) \simeq R(\mathrm{SL}_{2})$ is already explained well on Gross's article, and also $\mathcal{H}(\mathrm{GL}_{n}) \simeq R(\mathrm{GL}_{n})$, too. However, I cannot find a reference for the dual case ($\mathcal{H}(\mathrm{SL}_{n}) \simeq R(\mathrm{PGL}_{n})$). Especially, I want to know

the fundamental representations of $\mathrm{PGL}_{n}$ and
how they match with characteristic functions of double cosets $K \cdot \mathrm{diag}(\varpi^{a_1}, \dots, \varpi^{a_n}) \cdot K$ in $\mathcal{H}(\mathrm{SL}_{n})$ (here we have $a_1 + \cdots + a_n = 0$, and also we can assume $a_1 \ge \cdots \ge a_n$) under the Satake isomorphism.

Thanks in advance.
